# How to achieve equal-sized FormLayout across collapsible panels?

Tags: qt, layout, qt4

I think this might be two separated questions. In Qt4.8, the `QFormLayout` is

> The QFormLayout class manages forms of input widgets and their associated labels.
>
> QFormLayout is a convenience layout class that lays out its children in a two-column form. The left column consists of labels and the right column consists of "field" widgets (line editors, spin boxes, etc.).

Given the following image as a guide,

1) how to create two collapsible panels which can be collapsible correspondingly? Just like two blue rectangles? I have tried `QGroupBox` but there is no any *collapsible* attributes within.

2) how to make two separated `QFormLayout` have the same ratio of labels and fields even though they belongs to different collapsible panels? As in the attached image, we can tell those two formlayouts get aligned, as indicated by green lines.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have the code for the collapsible and need the code only for the `QFormLayout`. I believe this should do the trick.

The header file:

```
#pragma once

#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

class newQtApp : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

    public :
        newQtApp();
};
```

The source

```
newQtApp::newQtApp() : QMainWindow() {

    cout << "Im being initialized...." << endl;
    cout << "Setting window properties..." << endl;

    QFormLayout *fLyt1 = new QFormLayout();
    fLyt1->setLabelAlignment( Qt::AlignRight );
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        QLabel *lbl = new QLabel( QString( "Lyt 1, Label %1:" ).arg( i + 1), this );
        lbl->setFixedWidth( 150 );
        lbl->setAlignment( Qt::AlignRight );

        fLyt1->addRow( lbl, new QLineEdit() );
    }

    QGroupBox *w1 = new QGroupBox( "First Collapsible", this );
    w1->setLayout( fLyt1 );

    QFormLayout *fLyt2 = new QFormLayout();
    fLyt2->setLabelAlignment( Qt::AlignRight );
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        QLabel *lbl = new QLabel( QString( "Second Layout, Label %1:" ).arg( i + 1), this );
        lbl->setFixedWidth( 150 );
        lbl->setAlignment( Qt::AlignRight );

        fLyt2->addRow( lbl, new QCheckBox( "Check this out!!" ) );
    }

    QGroupBox *w2 = new QGroupBox( "Second Collapsible", this );
    w2->setLayout( fLyt2 );

    QVBoxLayout *baseLyt = new QVBoxLayout();
    baseLyt->addWidget( w1 );
    baseLyt->addWidget( w2 );

    QWidget *base = new QWidget( this );
    base->setLayout( baseLyt );

    setCentralWidget( base );
};
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]